# Bundling css and javascript with webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, webforms, bundle

I'm trying to bundle my css/js-files in my webforms project but it's not working.

This is what I've done:

- Included System.Web.Optimization via NuGet
- Added the code below to global.asax.cs in Application_Start

  ```
  BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js").Include("~/js/mainJS.js"));
  BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/css").Include("~/css/mainStyle.min.css"));
  ```
- Added this to my masterpage

  ```
  <%: Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS.js") %>
  <%: Styles.Render("~/css/mainStyle.min.css") %>
  ```

It renders the references to the css/js-files so the page is working but it's not generating a unique file name and it's not refering to the bundle folder like I expected.

I'm using VS2013 and Framework 4.0.

Comment: Are you compiling to release mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling in release mode

Comment: Are you sure you have `<compilation debug="false" />` in your web.config (this is independent from building in release mode)?

Comment: this is from my web.config file: <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="false"/>

Comment: I tried to do it from the code file and ad it to a asp:PlaceHolder like this this.PlhHeader.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js").ToHtmlString())); but it still just generates <script src="/js/mainJS.js"></script>

Comment: @WIRN Try forcing the minification by setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in `Application_Start`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Render() using the bundle name ("~/bundle/js") not the javascript file name ("~/js/mainJS.js").

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundle/js") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundle/css") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` inside your Application_Start event of Global.asax. Read [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/c72b040113-Asp.net-MVC-4-performance-optimization-with-bundling-and-minification.html) blog post for more information.